# Check whether all the pairs in an array are divisible by k

Tags: c++

> Given an array of integers and a number `k`, write a function that returns true if given array can be divided into pairs such that sum of every pair is divisible by `k`.

This code is producing correct results for all test cases except one I cannot find the glitch in it.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int t;
  cin >> t;
  while (t--) {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      cin >> arr[i];
    }
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    int flag[n] = {0};
    int p = 0;
    int q = 0;
    if (n % 2 != 0) {
      cout << "False" << endl;
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
          if ((arr[i] + arr[j]) % k == 0 && flag[j] == 0) {
            p = 1;
            flag[j] = 1;
          }
        }
        if (p == 0) {
          q = 1;
          cout << "False" << endl;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (q == 0) {
        cout << "True" << endl;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps step through it to find the issue?

Comment: The loop on `j` continues testing and setting `flag[j]` even after it has found a match, thus falsely marking additional elements as matches and making them unavailable to be matched with a future `arr[i]`. The loop should break once it has found a match. Additionally, `p` should be set to zero before each loop on `j`. Otherwise, once the loop has run once and successfully found a match and set `p` to 1, `p` remains 1 for future loops on `j`, so the test `p==0` never detects a failure.

Comment: In the future, when your code fails on a test case, **provide the input data for the test case in the question**, along with the observed output and the expected output.

Comment: Input:
62
32 20 37 87 46 3 23 68 69 24 94 76 62 64 91 64 1 72 19 14 14 73 12 97 97 48 29 79 11 69 93 43 88 81 81 34 36 55 53 4 78 46 31 39 9 22 54 61 45 72 26 11 96 37 7 92 36 35 23 99 56 67
40                                                                                                                                         Its Correct output is:
False

And Your Code's output is:
True

Comment: @EricPostpischil tried your suggestions it even produced wrong results that were previously right.

Comment: @J.Soumya: Upon changing `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` to `#include <iostream>`, changing `int flag[n]={0};` to `int flag[n]; memset(flag, 0, sizeof flag);`, inserting `p = 0;` before the loop on `j` and inserting `break;` after `flag[j]=1;`, and running the program with the above test data prefixed with “1 ”, the output is “False”.

Comment: It is giving wrong result

Comment: Don’t just say “It is giving wrong result”! You have been told once: give us a test case that it fails on. Surely that’s obvious?

Answer (score 2):

One of the big sources of bugs in code is messy code. So how do we clean up code? We modularize it. This means breaking up the code so that each portion of the code does one job well. Let's see what that looks like.

**Function to check if something is divisible by k:**

```
bool isDivisible(int number, int divisor) {
    return number % divisor == 0; 
}
```

**Function to check all pairs:** 
The logic is as follows:

1. Take the first number in the list; call in `n0`.
2. For every remaining number `n1`, check if that plus the first number is divisible by k
3. When we find `n1` such that `n0 + n1` is divisible by `k`,
   a. If the remaining numbers left over can also be split into divisible pairs, return true
   b. Otherwise, continue searching

4.If we've searched through all the numbers, return false.

```
bool pairsDivisible(int* nums, int count, int k) {
    if(count == 0) return true;
    if(count % 2 != 0) return false; // count must be even

    // 1.
    int n0 = nums[0]; 

    // 2.
    for(int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        int n1 = nums[i]; 

        // 3.
        if(isDivisible(n0 + n1, k)) {
            // Move the ith number so it's now nums[1]
            std::swap(nums[1], nums[i]); 

            if(pairsDivisible(nums + 2, count - 2, k)) {
                return true; // 3.a
            } else {
                // Reset the array
                std::swap(nums[1], nums[i]); 
            }
        }
    }
    return false; 
}
```